# iOS11 PDFView Memeory Leak

Tags: ios, pdfkit

I use `PDFView` to display PDFs. If I scroll quickly I get memory leaks.

```
let pdfView = PDFView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
self.view.insertSubview(pdfView, belowSubview: bottomBar)
pdfView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(topBar.snp.bottom).offset(8)
    make.left.equalTo(8)
    make.right.equalTo(-8)
    make.bottom.equalTo(-54)
}
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "swift", withExtension: "pdf")!
let doc = PDFDocument.init(url: url)
pdfView.document = doc
if let page = doc?.page(at: 0) {
    let rect = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
    let scale = (UIScreen.width - 16) / rect.width
    pdfView.minScaleFactor = scale
    pdfView.maxScaleFactor = scale
    pdfView.scaleFactor = scale
    pdfView.displaysPageBreaks = true
    pdfView.pageBreakMargins = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 8/scale, right: 0)
    pdfView.layoutDocumentView()
}
```

View Memory Graph Image

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: [Report a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com)?

Comment: My Question: Is that is bug or does my code cause memory leak?

Comment: any solution on memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to display your PDF in a WebView instead ?

Something like this :

```
let url = yourLocalURL
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!))
```

Comment: I have tried the way but some pdf annotation can't display in the webview